# Problemas para recuperar contenido de una tabla que fue eliminada y que extrañnamente esta en la base de datos master

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Hace unos días, elimine una base de datos en sql server management studio, ya que la misma me aparecía en estado recovery pending y al tratar de cambiarla de estado, perdí la información de las tablas. Al menos eso pensé, por lo tanto, decidí eliminarla y crearla de nuevo, sin embargo, al tratar de crearla, me generaba el siguiente error

```
CREATE DATABASE Gimnacio
Go
```

> Msg 5170, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
>   Cannot create file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Gimnacio.mdf' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.
>   Msg 1802, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

Lo cual me da a entender que la base de datos ya existe, lo cual es correcto, sin embargo, extrañamente tanto las tablas como los store procedures de esta BD aparecieron en la base de datos maestra. ¿Alguien sabe como puedo trasladar esa información a una nueva BD? Esto por cuanto como saben la master no puede cambiar de nombre y tampoco se puede eliminar,en un principio esta era la intención sin embrago la misma recibe toda la información de las demas BD y debe estar disponible para ssms pueda iniciarse, agradezco si alguien me puede ayudar con este tema

Comment: entonces probablemente no fue eliminada, fue que perdistes privilegios de lectura

Comment: En la base de datos master no aparece nada _"extrañamente"_, quizás alguna vez ejecutaste un script de creación de objetos en esa base de datos, y por eso _existen_ allí. Puedes extraer el script de creación, si ya no lo tienes y ejecutarlo en otra base de datos. Hecho esto, si las tablas tienen datos, puedes _moverlos_ haciendo un `insert into tabla select * from master.dbo.tabla`.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que existe es el archivo que contiene los datos de la base de datos. Ese archivo podría ser adjuntado para que SQL Server la reconozca como tal. La instrución sería algo así como

```
CREATE DATABASE Gimnacio
    ON (FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Gimnacio.mdf'),   
    (FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Gimnacio_Log.ldf')   
    FOR ATTACH;
```

O puedes usar un procedimiento almacenado que está deprecado y quitarán en una versión futura.

```
EXEC sp_attach_single_file_db @dbname = 'Gimnacio',   
    @physname =   
N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Gimnacio.mdf';
```

La razón por la que la base de datos estaba en modo Recovery es porque alguien la estaba restaurando y no completó el proceso. Es posible que eso genere problemas al momento de adjuntar el archivo para crear la base de datos.

Puedes encontrar más información en [la documentación de Microsoft.](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/databases/attach-a-database)